# WHERE CURRENT OF raising and invalid rowid error

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I'm trying to increase the age of every customer by 1 and display them; using a cursor.

This is the Table structure.

```
Select * from customers;

+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|  2 | Khilan   |  25 | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  4 | Chaitali |  25 | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  27 | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Komal    |  22 | MP        |  4500.00 |
```

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE
   c_id customers.id%TYPE;
   c_name customers.name%TYPE;
   c_age customers.age%TYPE;

   CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT id, name, age
      FROM customers
       FOR UPDATE OF salary;
BEGIN
   OPEN c1;
   LOOP
       FETCH c1 INTO c_id, c_name, c_age;
       UPDATE customers
       SET age = age + 1
       WHERE CURRENT OF c1;

       EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
       dbms_output.put_line( c_id || ' ' || c_name || ' ' || c_age );
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE c1;
END;
/
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Error report:
ORA-01410: invalid ROWID
ORA-06512: at line 13
01410. 00000 -  "invalid ROWID"
*Cause:    
*Action:
1 Ramesh 32
2 Khilan 25
3 kaushik 23
4 Chaitali 25
5 Hardik 27
6 Komal 22
```

Why is this happening and how can I stop it?

Comment: Please, format the question

Comment: You can suggest edits @rpax and this is the OPs first post. It might be more helpful to format the question yourself and give guidance on how to do it in the future.

Comment: Thanks @rpax. I tried formatting it from my end but couldn't do much. Any tips for formatting would be helpful too.

Comment: @Ben Sorry, It's difficult to edit a question from my mobile phone. WamglindCarmasaic, you can take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Is table "customers" actually a view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have your `exit` in the wrong place; it should be straight after the `fetch`. You are processing your six real rows properly, but then you have a seventh fetch - after which `%notfound` will be `true` - so there is no 'current' row to update. You need to exit before you try to do anything with that invalid row.

```
BEGIN
   OPEN c1;
   LOOP
       FETCH c1 INTO c_id, c_name, c_age;
       EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

       UPDATE customers
       SET age = age + 1
       WHERE CURRENT OF c1;

       dbms_output.put_line( c_id || ' ' || c_name || ' ' || c_age );
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE c1;
END;
```

Hopefully this is just an exercise, as it's not a very efficient way to do the updates.

Comment: Thanks Alex. It works fine now. And yes, it was just for practice :)